# why cannot I apply a predicate to java stream filter?

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I have this code:

```
@Override
public List<Device> getAvailableDevices(Predicate<Device> filter) {
    return deviceRepository.getDevices()
            .stream()
            .filter(filter)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error:(55, 25) java: incompatible types: com.google.common.base.Predicate<com.m.automation.common.mobile.services.devices.dataModel.Device> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super com.m.automation.common.mobile.services.devices.dataModel.Device>
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Those are two different predicate types

Comment: You might be able to use a method reference off the Guava type (i.e. `filter::apply`)

Comment: You're importing the wrong `Predicate` type: it should be `java.util.function.Predicate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Guava predicate, rather than a `java.util.function.Predicate`. This is determined by the `import` statements in your source file.

If you can alter this code and its callers, change the type of this `getAvailableDevices()` method to accept `java.util.function.Predicate`. Simply changing your import directive will accomplish that, but it might impact other code; if you really want to keep using Guava predicates elsewhere, you can target the change to this method by using the fully-qualified name, `java.util.function.Predicate`.

If you can't make a change to this method signature, adapt the filter you have to a standard `Predicate` by replacing `filter(filter)` with `filter(filter::apply)`.